# XamarinForms Shell OnResume - previous page is showing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to achieve lock mechanism in XF 4.5.0 Shell app.

I have static timer that counts how much seconds passed, and based on some logic present either screen that user was before put the app in behind (user went to instagram, but app is in the background running)

So, my `OnResume()` method looks like this:

```
private bool IsUserExists()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GlobalAppSettings.Email) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GlobalAppSettings.Password) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GlobalAppSettings.Pin))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            if ((!OnSleepOrPauseTime.HasValue || OnSleepOrPauseTime.Value.AddSeconds(5) <= DateTime.Now)
                &&(IsUserExists()))
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(Routes.LoginPinPage, false);
                });
            }
        }
```

**The problem**: user sees for a like half second the screen where he was before, and then it redirects to LoginPinPage.

**The happy path**: Should be that user doesnt see that flickering page that was before exiting form an app, just immediately lock screen.

**Possible solution:** That crossed on my mind, before leaving the app to somehow redirect in background app to login pin screen?

Comment: If you want to achieve timing function in the background, In the Android, you should use forground service and `AlarmManager` to achieve it, when your application is background, you should use dependency serivce to open a forground service(keep the application alive in background), use `AlarmManager` to timing, when timing is over, use MessageCenter to send a message from Droid to PCL, then navigate the login ping screen.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT basically its odd that someone doesnt have some nuget or example for lock screen OnResume() ? Do you have an example of this messaging cnter communication between Droid -> PCL also, I need this and for iOS too.

Comment: Please see this thread (Line 70) that use messageCenter in Droid Folder 
 https://github.com/851265601/MapUseMessageCenter/blob/master/MapUseMessageCenter/Droid/CustomMapRenderer.cs   Then used it in PCL.https://github.com/851265601/MapUseMessageCenter/blob/master/MapUseMessageCenter/CustomRenderer/MapPage.xaml.cs

Comment: ok, but how to incorporate this in ios project too_

Comment: MessagingCenter used in IOS project, it is same as android.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT can you please add an example for messaging center?

Comment: Please see Emixam23 's answer, it give 
 a example in Android, iOS, Windows, UWP https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/206862#Comment_206862

Answer (score 0):

PushAsync has 2 overloads - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.inavigation.pushasync?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_INavigation_PushAsync_Xamarin_Forms_Page_System_Boolean_)

By default the `PushAsync` method pushes the new page **with** animation. I think that this is the so-called "flickering" that you are referring to.
You can try to use the second overload and pass *false* for the `animated` property and see if it makes any difference.

```cs
PushAsync(new LoginPinPage(), false);
```

If you want to redirect the user on app leave - you can use another of the `Application`'s lifecycle methods - `OnSleep` and invoke your navigation there. But I suggest to try it without animations first.

Keep in mind that, should you choose to use the `OnSleep` method, you will also have to push the page **without** animations. I have just tested pushing with animations and I do indeed see the flickering that you are mentioning. Setting the `animated` flag to *false*, removed any flickering for me.

Comment: the behavior is the same with animation turned to false. Tested on honor mobile android 9

Comment: Do you have any logic in OnSleep method? Also, is this the only code in the OnResume method? Is it possible that IsUserExists takes a bit of time and it is blocking the check?

Comment: Please see my update. I put also the private method `IsUesrExists()`. I do not have overriden method OnSleep() yet

Comment: I commented everything in OnResume() method except redirection to a PinPage and again its the same, I can see previous page..

Comment: I see that you changed the way you are pushing the new page - instead of Navigation's PushAsync method, you are using Shell's GoToAsync. I haven't tested it this way. If it is flickering again, then I suggest that you try the OnSleep one. Unfortunately, I don't know what the logic for pushing is (the OnSleepOrPauseTime prop), but you can try to put it there. If it calculates some seconds after the app has been put to background, you can start a timer and use it to count the seconds.

Comment: I just tried via registrating the route, instead of classic navigation xf..but still the same..